# What capacities should have a hosting to support an average of 1000 registered users simultaneously?

Tags: hosting, bandwidth, disk-space-utilization, host, capacity-planning

How much RAM, Disk Space, Bandwidth, etc would be needed?

It's just and aproximate. I have no idea how to do a real implementation of a web service and I'm not going to, but I have to write a SRS (software requeriments specifications) and I need to know approximately this specifications.

Comment: Hire someone who does this for a living.

Comment: Do we have a canonical "Size my server for my wholly unspecified application" question we can close these as exact-dupe of? I haven't kept up on my "meta". Hmm... maybe I'll go over there and post a question. It would be nice to see what the UI for asking a question looks like today... >smile<

Comment: @Evan: Yeah, the canonical duplicate is "Not a real question"

Comment: Meta discusion: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2980/canonical-help-me-size-my-wholly-unspecified-application-question

Answer (score 2):

This depends mostly on the type of the application you will run and on the usage pattern of the users.

Comment: The majority of resource problems stem from CPU use, or disk IO, bad MySQL queries, and other runaway scripts

Comment: It's a web page for virtual class. Teachers put homeworks, students complete those homeworks. It also have to be able to make videoconferences between teachers and student. And basically, that's all.